# Can you get INTERmission without buying FF7R again?

Tags: final-fantasy-7-remake

Played FF7R on PS4, and now that I have a PS5 I wanted to play intermission.

But it seems my only option is intergrade, that is FF7R for PS5 plus the INTERmission.

Since I already played and own FF7R and I am not interested in paying for it again just for intermission, is there any other way to get Intermission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you do not need to re-purchase Final Fantasy 7 Remake in order to play INTERMission. Since you originally played on the PS4, you'll need to upgrade your version to the PS5 version (free of charge). Once your account has the PS5 version, you'll be able to purchase the [INTERMission](https://store.playstation.com/en-us/product/UP0082-PPSA01903_00-8094607291671776) upgrade independently for only $20 (USD)