# Is it possible to get FF7 Remake Intermission from used physical copies of FF7Remake PS4/PS5 Intergrade?

Tags: final-fantasy-7-remake

I started with a rental copy of FF7Remake for PS4, uploaded my save and redownloaded the save for PS5 (also rental copy). I cannot download/purchase Intermission from what I've tried and searched so far. All copies are physical.

Is there no way to get Intermission for free.

Comment: [Related, possibly dup](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/400446/124566). The question appears to be for the digital version rather than physical, but theoretically it would work somewhat the same

Comment: @Wondercricket I don't think it's a dupe, as I don't have the option to digitally upgrade to PS5 as I already installed the PS5 version of the game from a used physical copy of the PS5 game, moreover the final answer of that question is to purchase the DLC, where I am wondering if it possible for me to get it for free since I have a physical copy of PS5 intergrade and the box says it's included

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't realize the Intermission DLC was included in the PS5 physical version of.  If that's the case, have you tried launching the game and seeing if you can access the DLC from the start menu?

Comment: @Wondercricket no, doesn't show up as an option to launch, playstation store doesn't give offer to buy, only learn more, manage game content doesn't allow any manipulation of anything

Answer (score 0):

After doing some digging, unfortunately you probably have to purchase the INTERMission DLC separately. Based on [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/FFVIIRemake/comments/xu7vvx/intermission_dlc_code_for_a_used_copy_of_the_game/) Reddit thread, which the user purchased a used physical copy of FF7R for the PS5, it would appear that the INTERMission DLC is not directly include in the FF7R disc, but rather a digital redemption code is included in new copies.

Therefore, since you are using a "rental copy", you didn't not obtain the redemption code for the INTERMission DLC